# Washing hands in the morning/Wrapping hand tefilin according to Rambam

Tags: halacha, rambam, mysticism-kabbalah, sheidim-demons, rationalism

I'm curious as to communities (or even individuals) that follow Rambam w/o any zoharic or kabbalistic influence (e.g. R Y. Kapach/Kafih/Qafih's if it isn't already extinct), how do they wash their hands in the morning and wrap their hand tefilin?

(Rambam doesn't mention "negel vasser" as it was based on ruach raah/sheidim which Rambam doesn't subscribe to nor the 7 arm wrappings which are of kabbalistic origin and mimic the 7 lower sefiros which again Rambam rejects.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> R Y. Kapach/Kafih/Qafih's if it isn't already extinct

R. Qafih's tradition is alive and strong. One of his primary disciples, [R. Rason 'Arusi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratzon_Arusi) (a tremendous talmid hakham in his own right) is perhaps the most well known, however there are many others as well.

> how do they wash their hands in the morning... Rambam doesn't mention "negel vasser" as it was based on ruach raah/sheidim which Rambam doesn't subscribe to

According to the Rambam, washing is a preparatory function of tefillah. It is one of the five things that are me'akbhin eth ha-tefillah (H. Tefillah 4:1). So washing upon waking is unnecessary and only becomes obligatory before one intends to pray. It can be done at any time before prayer as long as one maintains mindfulness of their hand activity (H. Berakhoth 6:17). To my observation, this is how the community indeed observes the halakhah.

> how do they... wrap their hand tefilin? ... Rambam doesn't subscribe to... the 7 arm wrappings which are of kabbalistic origin and mimic the 7 lower sefiros which again Rambam rejects.

Here is how R. Itamar Kohen (an active member of the Dardai community) describes it in [Mishnath ha-Rambam](https://mishnatharambam.blogspot.com/2018/04/blog-post_72.html):

> לשון הרמב"ם בהלכות תפילין ג,יב: ואורך רצועה של יד, כדי שתקיף את הזרוע
> ויקשור ממנה הקשר, ותמתח רצועה אחת עד אצבע אמצעית, ויכרוך ממנה על אצבעו
> שלוש כריכות ויקשור. ע"כ. **למדנו מדבריו כי מסביב לקיבורת די בכריכה
> אחת, ושתי הכריכות הנוספות הם מנהג, וכן שבע הכריכות מסביב לזרוע הם
> מנהג.**

That it is a function of minhag, there is no halakhah concerning it. So if one has a specific custom to wrap a certain number of times (be it 7 or any other number) they may do so. In the Baladi community (which R. Qafih and his talmidim are a subset of), the predominant custom is seven (I have seen other variations but never asked). However as R. 'Arusi [points out](https://net-sah.org/faq/48750):

> שבע הכריכות אינן מעכבות

Comment: Great halachic presentation along with fascinating info regarding R Qafih's adherents. You're getting an upvote from me but not a check as I am aware of Rambams halachic position on these issues, I'm more interested in the actual practices/minhagim of a community that strictly follows Rambam as it relates to these two particular matters. Thanks!

Comment: Btw, I love your Hebrew pronunciation—you seem to be one of the faithful!

Comment: These sources reflect how this community actually practices. People wash when suits their convenience before prayer, not necessarily upon awakening. And as far as number of wraps, it is varied - with the predominantly practiced custom being seven.

Comment: Do you happen to know the source (and purpose) for Rambam's writing to wrap the retzuah around the finger three times? (Because if I didn't know better it would seem to be the 3 higher sefiros complementing the lower ones symbolized by the 7 arm wrappings)

Comment: [H. Tefillin 3:12](https://mechon-mamre.org/i/2303.htm) and also discusses it in a [teshubhah (no. 159 of vol. 2 of the Blau)](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1731&pgnum=27) where he notably states that אין הקשר על האצבע מוכרח. As for it somehow being kabbalistically symbolic - there is nothing in the Rambam to suggest that.

Comment: You misunderstand me. I get that it highly unlikely to be based on kabbalah. I am wondering what Rambam's (in tefilin 3:12) source is for 3 finger wrappings and was saying that if I didn't know better—however I do and can't imagine that it has any kabbalistic significance—I'd say that it complements the 7.

Comment: As an aside, I'm curious, should you know, approximately how many families is the dardai community currently comprised of? Also, where is it mostly based? Tia

Comment: I may be mistaken, but to my recollection there isn't an explicit Talmudic source.  So I do not know where he gets it from. Perhaps it was נתפשט in the Geonic era, and he therefore recorded it. I am curious too but do not know. As far as complimenting 7, I think that would be a strange claim to make based on the Rambam as he does not mention it.

Comment: I really can't say a number, not everyone is overt about it and it is enmeshed with the larger Baladi community. Also, I think it is kind of operates along a spectrum, with some leaning to greater or lesser degrees that way. The largest concentration would be around Qiryath Ono but there are individuals/pockets all throughout the country (Jerusalem, TA, various yishibhim, etc.)

Comment: Thank you. I get that as well. I was merely saying that the 3 would seem to pair nicely with the 7 in the world of (proto-)kabbalah and would shed light on the minhag altho it is highly unlikely that the Rambam sees it that way. Ok, no matter. Pls lmk if you indeed come across a source for the 3 finger wrappings. Much thanks for sharing all this knowledge & information.

Comment: Will do... I am curious as well. Perhaps create a new question and post it?

Comment: Ok, will do. (15 characters)

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/139365/source-for-winding-retzuos-around-the-finger-3-times

Comment: Good answer. Just wanted to share there are a lot more dor daim than most people realize. Like my friend said above, many do not advertise it. Especially because some people react very negatively, some view dor daim as heretics or nearly heretics, so a lot of dor dai tend to stay quiet about it, for better or for worse.

Comment: @BID I hear you. It's ironic as presumably the rationalist geonim and rishonim would term the kabbalistic perception of God a complete heresy.